# SQL, count in multiple columns then group by

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, group-by

I am trying to count in multiple columns then group by for a total sum where the same data appears in any column

```
Source data table:

P1  P2  P3
-----------
a   b   
a   a   a
b   c   
a   b   b
b   a
```

I want it to show something like this:

```
Desired query output:

     Total
   -------------
a |    6
b |    5
c |    1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a union query

```
SELECT x.f1,Count(x.f1) FROM
(SELECT p1 As F1 FROM table
 UNION ALL
 SELECT p2 As F1 FROM table
 UNION ALL
 SELECT p3 As F1 FROM table) x
GROUP BY x.f1
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the NULL, then you should have a where clause to remove NULL values.

Answer (score 5):

You can `union all` the records in a subquery and on the outer query, `count` each value.

```
SELECT b.a, COUNT(b.a)
FROM
    (
        SELECT P1 a
        FROM tableName
        UNION ALL
        SELECT P2 a
        FROM tableName
        UNION ALL
        SELECT P3 a
        FROM tableName
    ) b
GROUP BY b.a
```

Comment: You have used UNION which will eliminate duplicates.