# Why is my SQL Union Query Returning Different Values than my manual SELECT WHERE query?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am querying a table (my table has NULL values) using this sql code:

```
SELECT x.f1,Count(x.f1) FROM
(SELECT p1 As F1 FROM table
 UNION ALL
 SELECT p2 As F1 FROM table
 UNION ALL
 SELECT p3 As F1 FROM table) x
GROUP BY x.f1
```

This code achieves the question this user asked: 
[SQL, count in multiple columns then group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354207/sql-count-in-multiple-columns-then-group-by)

However, when I manually test how many counts a certain item in my table gets using this statement on all columns:

```
WHERE col1 or col2 or col3, etc = 'entry name'
```

, I get a different number of counts of that entry as with the union query. The union query either overshoots the amount of the manual query or equals the manual query (what I want). For example, for a certain entry, the manual query will return 2 and the union query will return 4.

I realize this question is a bit vague because I cannot disclose my table info nor my exact query, but I want to know whether I'm missing something important. Thanks!

PS. I am using MS SQL server 2012

**EDIT: EXAMPLE (taken from previous user's post), for clarification:**

Source data table:

```
P1  P2  P3
-----------
a   b   
a   a   a
b   c   
a   b   b
b   a
```

I want it to show something like this:

Desired query output:

```
     Total
   -------------
a |    6
b |    5
c |    1
```

Using the UNION query code above for MY table, I will get 12 as the total count for 'a.' Using my manual query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE P1 = 'a' OR P2 = 'a' OR P3 ='a'
```

, I will get 6 for the total count.

My question is, shouldn't both queries return the same value?

Comment: I understand the need for secrecy, but it would really help if you could contrive an actual example that we can try and play along with. As stated, the question is terribly vague.

Comment: I will do that, give me a few min

Comment: How can the table be so secret that we cannot see it, as long as you don't share any data?

Comment: sorry about that Golez, I added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First there really is no reason to think that the two queries would return similar results.  The one with the `where` clause is counting rows, regardless of the number of matches.  The one with `union all` could count each row up to three times, depending on the values in `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`.

To count rows with the `union all`, you need an id to identify each row.  Then you can use `count(distinct id)` in the outer query.

Comment: Well, you *could* have the ID on every row, but it really seems like the nature of the question is that we want `OR`-type logic. `UNION` is just not the appropriate tool to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`col1 or col2 or col3, etc = 'entry name'` is not the right syntax. It just checks if `col1` and `col2` have any value. Only the last one in the list is checked against the actual value `'entry name'`.

Answer (score 0):

The `UNION` way runs three times through the table looking for matches, and will count the same row twice if it has the matching value in more than one column. The `OR` way runs through the table just once and won't double-count anything.

Remember, `UNION` doesn't combine your conditions; it combines *the actual rows output* from each component query. It's not at all the same thing as using `OR`.